# iOS and libxml compiler warning question

Tags: ios, compiler-warnings, libxml2

I'm loading some xml from a file... here's a snippet of the file:

```
<root>

    <person>
        <age>99</age>
        <name>bob</name>
    </person>

    <person>
        <age>199</age>
        <name>bill</name>
    </person>
    ...
</root>
```

I'm using libxml in an iOS app.  This line of code:

```
if([[NSString stringWithUTF8String:cur_node->name] isEqualToString:@"name"]){
```

is giving me this compiler warning:

```
Pointer targets in passing argument 1 of 'stringWithUTF8String:' differ in signedness
```

**What does this warning mean and how can I get rid of it?**

Cheers!

Edit:  casting cur_node->name as a (const char *) removed the warnings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this forum post](http://www.boards.ie/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=2055443436), there are 3 kinds of C character types:

```
char
unsigned char
signed char
```

Basically, the libxml property you are accessing (cur_node->name) is likely `unsigned char *` or `signed char *`, whereas `stringWithUTF8String:` is expecting a different type (`const char *`).

A similar issue is [here on iPhoneDevSDK Forums](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/46040-differ-signedness-why.html).

If your code works, casting may be an easy way to get rid of the warning.